# Docker image build failed Error response from daemon

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

I am building Angular app with nginx image while creating Docker build step Jenkins build getting failed with below error message. could you please help why the Docker is not allowing me to build the images

Docker file

```
# base image
FROM node:13.3.0 AS build

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install

# add app
COPY . /app

FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Next here the jnkinsfile stage for building docker image

```
 stage('Build Docker Image') {
            container('docker') {
              echo 'docker'
              sh "docker build -t username/${image_name}:${image_tag} ."
              sh "docker tag ${image_name} ${image_name}:${image_tag}"           
        }
      }
```

jenkins build logs

```
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build Docker Image)
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
docker
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker build -t username/frontend-app:master-49089c41 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 557.1 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 1.114 MB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 1.671 MB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.228 MB

Step 1/9 : FROM node:13.3.0 AS build
 ---> 2af77b226ea7
Step 2/9 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> afd7b5b6b236
Step 3/9 : ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2b2a5ea72fe1
Step 4/9 : COPY package.json /app/package.json
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a7c4dbcd6421
Step 5/9 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 281815d7cd02
Step 6/9 : COPY . /app
 ---> f1ef0f9eebe1
Step 7/9 : FROM nginx
 ---> 62d49f9bab67
Step 8/9 : COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a53597248ccf
Step 9/9 : COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
 ---> d85d9b9cda00
Successfully built d85d9b9cda00
Successfully tagged username/frontend-app:master-49089c41
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker tag frontend-app frontend-app:master-49089c41
Error response from daemon: No such image: frontend-app:latest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `docker tag` command, you're trying to use a source image that does not exist. You need to specify the full name of the image, in your case with `username` and tag you've just created. What's happening here is that Docker tries to find `frontend-app` with the default tag (latest), but you should instruct it to look for `frontend-app:master-49089c41`

Try to change it to something like this:

```
 stage('Build Docker Image') {
            container('docker') {
              echo 'docker'
              sh "docker build -t username/${image_name}:${image_tag} ."
              sh "docker tag username/${image_name}:${image_tag} ${image_name}:${image_tag}"           
        }
      }
```

Comment: Hi Michal Thanks for your inputs now the jenkins pipeline went successfully with message of output from the docker image command Successfully tagged username/frontend-app:master-3b2e2b57